# How to follow a COM IntPtr in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, uwp, marshalling, unity-game-engine

So I am attempting to follow an unsafe ptr in Unity so I can control the exposure length of a camera. However, I am at a loss of how to actually derefence the ptr. As I understand, the ptr refers to a non-managed object so I need to somehow Marshall it assume? I am unfamiliar with interacting in ptrs in C#. I have already successfully compiled an unsafe version of the code, I just need to figure out what to do with the IntPtr.

For reference, I am using the Hololens Toolkit API. The documentation also suggests I need to release it afterwards. How would I go about access the functions I need to actually call on the VideoDeviceManager.

Comment: If you use [the HoloLens preview build of Unity](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/unity_development_overview) you might find it easier to do than working with the raw toolkit, that way you can use the managed wrappers that Unity will write instead of writing your own from the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dereference a pointer by calling [Marshal.PtrToStructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx). To use it you need to describe your targeted object's layout in your own custom structure type.

Comment: It's a DOM pointer so I actually figured out that I need to use Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: DOM=COM? Then yeap, probably. Sorry, I'm not much into Unity.